# Excel code, my 'add data' button is not working

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I am new to coding and have got this far by googling.  I am hoping it is a fairly simple change in the code.  I have a form which shows what I want it to.  My close button works however my 'add data' button doesn't work.  As in it isn't populating the information I enter into the completed form to the worksheet in excel.  I get the first column populating always with 0.1, no matter what I enter in.  Here is my code if anyone would like to assist.  I would be very grateful.

```
Private Sub cmdbutton_add_Click()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Inputs")

'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

'Check for a Name number
If Trim(Me.textbox_lineno.Value) = " " Then
Me.textbox_lineno.SetFocus
MsgBox "Please Complete the form"
Exit Sub
End If

'copy the data to the database
ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.textbox_lineno.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.listbox_pipetype.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.textbox_frompit.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.textbox_topitormh.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.textbox_linealm.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.textbox_depthstart.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.textbox_depthend.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.textbox_pipedia.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.textbox_beddingbelow.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.textbox_beddingabove.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.textbox_roadallowance.Value

MsgBox "Data Added", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Data Added"

'Clear the data
Me.textbox_lineno.Value = ""
Me.listbox_pipetype.Value = ""
Me.textbox_frompit.Value = ""
Me.textbox_topitormh.Value = ""
Me.textbox_linealm.Value = ""
Me.textbox_depthstart.Value = ""
Me.textbox_depthend.Value = ""
Me.textbox_pipedia.Value = ""
Me.textbox_beddingbelow.Value = ""
Me.textbox_beddingabove.Value = ""
Me.textbox_roadallowance.Value = ""
Me.textbox_lineno.SetFocus
End Sub







Private Sub cmdbutton_close_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Did youtry debugging your code. If not Set a breakpoint at the statement Set ws = Worksheets("Inputs") and then debug the code.

Comment: Hi There,Yes I debugged it. so not sure what to do now.

Answer (score 1):

This line should never validate:

`If Trim(Me.textbox_lineno.Value) = " " Then`

You never increment your column assignments.  If I know that an Object exists then I will usually opt for a `With Object` statement over using another variable.

I extracted the code for clearing the textboxes into their own sub routine.

Because all the data is on one row and `With .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Offset(1)` refers the first cell of that row I use `Columns(x)` which is analogous to using `.Cells(1,x)`.  I fell like it looks cleaner.

I feel like these alterations to consolidate the code; make it easier to read.  You don't have to scroll up and down the page to see just what the sub is doing.

---

```
Private Sub cmdbutton_add_Click()
    'Check for a Name number
    If Trim(Me.textbox_lineno.Value) = "" Then
        Me.textbox_lineno.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Please Complete the form", vbInformation, "Action Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Worksheets("Inputs")
        With .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Offset(1)
            'copy the data to the database
            .Columns(1).Value = Me.textbox_lineno.Value
            .Columns(2).Value = Me.listbox_pipetype.Value
            .Columns(3).Value = Me.textbox_frompit.Value
            .Columns(4).Value = Me.textbox_topitormh.Value
            .Columns(5).Value = Me.textbox_linealm.Value
            .Columns(6).Value = Me.textbox_depthstart.Value
            .Columns(7).Value = Me.textbox_depthend.Value
            .Columns(8).Value = Me.textbox_pipedia.Value
            .Columns(9).Value = Me.textbox_beddingbelow.Value
            .Columns(10).Value = Me.textbox_beddingabove.Value
            .Columns(11).Value = Me.textbox_roadallowance.Value
        End With
    End With

    MsgBox "Data Added", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Data Added"

    ClearForm

    Me.textbox_lineno.SetFocus
End Sub

Function ClearForm()
    'Clear the data
    Me.textbox_lineno.Value = ""
    Me.listbox_pipetype.Value = ""
    Me.textbox_frompit.Value = ""
    Me.textbox_topitormh.Value = ""
    Me.textbox_linealm.Value = ""
    Me.textbox_depthstart.Value = ""
    Me.textbox_depthend.Value = ""
    Me.textbox_pipedia.Value = ""
    Me.textbox_beddingbelow.Value = ""
    Me.textbox_beddingabove.Value = ""
    Me.textbox_roadallowance.Value = ""
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Hi There,  Thank you. I cut and pasted this code it, but it didn't work either. It did change things, I can complete the form and when I hit add data button it populates the first 6 rows with all the same data that I entered into the form.  Ultimately what I need is to complete numerous forms and then it populate one table so it needs to search for the next free row and populate the row with the form completed.

Comment: @khup I just created a test for my code (See Updates Answer).  It performs as expected.  If there are 6 rows of data being added then the button click event is getting called 6 times.